# Выборка записей из БД, отсортированных произвольным образом

Tags: mysql, sql, сортировка

Нужно сделать выборку всех записей из БД, отсортированных произвольным образом, т.е. при каждой повторной выборке порядок записей отличался

Comment: Но во всех РСУБД как бы так и есть... Строки/записи/кортежи без сортировки выводятся как попало. Если нарочно нужно рандомизировать, то можно написать функцию.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον *во всех РСУБД как бы так и есть... Строки/записи/кортежи без сортировки выводятся как попало.* В общем случае это неверно. Они выводятся не "как попало", а как дешевле. Для одной таблицы без обработок, условий и сортировок это почти всегда - в порядке следования записей в кластерном индексе. И при двух последовательных выборках без изменения данных между выборками порядок записей, как правило, воспроизводится.

Comment: @Akina, где как наврное. У нас есть сайт (я к нему отношения не имею =), так там записи в выпадающем списке были упорядоченны по разному при каждом его открытии. Я не заню из-за чего такое было, но возможно это от СУБД так.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Записи, прежде чем быть показанными в выпадающем списке, не только возвращались запросом, но и проходили ещё кучу промежуточных "инстанций", каждая из которых могла поучаствовать в порядке следования значений. Как явно, так и скрыто, by design соответствующего промежуточного объекта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Многие диалекты *SQL* поддерживают что-то типа такого:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t_1
 ORDER BY RANDOM()
;
```

Это работает в *PostgreSQL* и *SQLite*. В *MySQL* 8.0
нужно заменить `RANDOM()` на `RAND()`.  Есть также
специфичные для конкретной СУБД техники оптимизации, но для большинства
ежедневных задач такая конструкция подойдёт.

Comment: Добавил метку mysql. Думаю такой вариант мне подойдет, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать запрос к БД, получить массив записей и воспользоваться функцией shuffle (Если вы используете php - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php) для того, чтобы перемешать записи. Обычным запросом sql здесь не обойдется

Comment: Обычным SQL-запросом обойдется практически в любой СУБД. почти во всех современных БД есть функция rand() или аналогичная, по которой можно отсортировать

Comment: Я голосую против этого ответа, потому что он фактически неверен и предлагает вредные практики.

Comment: *получить массив записей и воспользоваться функцией shuffle* Это требует копирования набора записей в массив - на месте не получится.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать